# Force template deduction from a function to produce const references where applicable

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

running through the following function using gdb in vscode tells me that the deduced argTypes for a function of the form `T (*)(const int &, const int *, int &, int)` are `int` `const int *` `int &` and `int` respectively. Is there any way to force the compiler to deduce `const Type &` when presented with a `const Type &` argument? Or is there some other means by which I can extract that type information in a useful way?

```
#include<typeinfo>

template<typename T, typename...argTypes>
void testfunc(T (*f)(argTypes...))
{
    const char *a[] = { typeid(argTypes).name()... };
    for(auto &av :a)
    {
        std::cout << av << std::endl;
    }
}
```

edit:
A little more context: this function obviously does little to nothing, but the problem function that spawned it also takes in all the arguments to be run with f in a way that they are not deduced, but converted.
This presents a problem for non-copyable objects to be used as const references.

An example of using `testfunc` is as follows:

```
#include "testfunc.h"

std::vector<bool> funcToTest(const int &a, const int *b, int &c, int d)
{
    std::vector<bool> out;
    out.push_back(&a == b);
    out.push_back(&c == b);
    out.push_back(&d == b);
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    // put a breakpoint here, and step in, you would see that 'a'
    // describes the situation as described above.
    testfunc(funcToTest);
}
```

Comment: How do you use `testfunc`? Probably types should be the same with function you pass

Comment: Cannot reproduce: my gdb say that the function called is `testfunc<void, int const&, int const*, int&, int>` (where `void` is `T`, the returned type).

Comment: Is this a situation where [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) could be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is with `typeid`, not template deduction.  If you use

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct types;

template<typename T, typename...argTypes>
void testfunc(T (*f)(argTypes...))
{

    types<argTypes...>{};
}
```

You get an nice error message like

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void testfunc(T (*)(argTypes ...)) [with T = std::vector<bool>; argTypes = {const int&, const int*, int&, int}]':
main.cpp:30:24:   required from here
main.cpp:12:5: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct types<const int&, const int*, int&, int>'
   12 |     types<argTypes...>{};
      |     ^~~~~
main.cpp:7:8: note: declaration of 'struct types<const int&, const int*, int&, int>'
    7 | struct types;
      |        ^~~~~
```

which shows you that the function parameter types are correctly deduced.

With `typeid` if the type is a reference, then it returns the referred to type.  It also drops all cv-qualifactions on the types.  That means

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(int).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(int&).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(const int).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(const int&).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(volatile int).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(volatile int&).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(const volatile int).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(const volatile int&).name() << "\n";
}
```

prints

```
i
i
i
i
i
i
i
i
```

Comment: Thanks, armed with this new knowledge I will hopefully be able to make progress on whatever the actual issue is.